# Change the "Submitted by" date type?

Tags: 7, theming, datetime

By default, in Drupal 7, the "Submitted by" date type is set to Medium.  I want the "Submitted by" date to be rendered using a different type.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard-coded into [`template_preprocess_node()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) so to override it you'll need to implement your own preprocess function, either in a theme or custom module:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (variable_get('node_submitted_' . $vars['node']->type, TRUE)) {
    $date = format_date($vars['node']->created, 'date_type');
    $vars['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $vars['name'], '!datetime' => $date));
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, really hard-coded :).

Answer (score 2):

also If you wont(or couldn't) do it in theme(for any reason) .You can do it in your custom module.

```
function yourmodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

   $variables['date']= format_date($variables['created'] ,'your date format');
   $variables['submitted'] = $variables['date'] . ' — ' . $variables['name'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go to admin/config/regional/date-time/formats and add a new format using PHP date formats  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

then go to admin/config/regional/date-time and change Medium to your new added format.

Answer (score 0):

The glazed theme does it as such:

```
// BLOG NODES
  if ($vars['type'] == 'blog') {
    $_created_date = format_date($vars['node']->created, 'custom', 'M j, Y');
    $vars['submitted'] = '<em class="text-muted">' . $_created_date . ' ' . t('By') . ' </em> <span class="glazed-util-text-uppercase">' . $vars['node']->name . '</span>';
  }
```